# Mechanism of preparation of methylene blue

Tags: reaction-mechanism

Methylene blue is prepared by reacting p-amino N,N dimethylaniline with strong acidic solution of $\ce{Na2S}$ and later adding aqueous $\ce{FeCl3}$. In this reaction does the mechanism begin with the addition of proton on amino which then undergoes substitution with another of the substituted aniline molecule?
Also how does sulfur attach to the ring?